# Convert JSON to CSV using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a sample JSON-formatted [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1qthGVt8jpnQkNnbEZJV0YzaUE) which converts fine if I use something like: https://konklone.io/json/

I've tried the following code in PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json) 
| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation 
| Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

But the only result I get is this:

```
{"totalCount":19,"resultCount":19,"hasMore":false,"results":
```

How do I go about converting this correctly in PowerShell?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By looking at just `(Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json` it looks like the rest of the JSON is going in to a `results` property so we can get the result I think you want by doing:

```
((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json).results |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

FYI you can do `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Set-Content` in one move with `Export-CSV`:

```
((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json).results |
    Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: For some reason, on my end, the array contained in source json file is converted to the "SyncRoot" property of the results. So I just had to replace .results with .SyncRoot.

Comment: @DanyGauthier that is because .results is the name of JSON object. I guess you have a name called "SyncRoot". I have a name called "Weights". That messed with me for a while, but once I figured it out it worked :)

Comment: I specifically had to leave out the ".results" (and added -Raw as my json was 'formatted' for readability: `((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json) | Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation`
PowerShell version 4 if it matters.

Comment: Upvoted, I also had to strip out the `.results` from the one-liner.

Comment: and me - no need for .results in my script

Answer (score 9):

You have to select the `results` property inside your CSV using the `Select-Object` cmdlet together with the `-expand` parameter:

```
Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile  | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object -expand results | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting my json from a REST web api and found that the following worked:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -method GET -uri $RemoteHost -Headers $headers 
 | ConvertFrom-Json 
 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  <Name of object in json>
 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation 
 | Set-Content $pathToOutputFile

I end up with a perfectly formatted csv file
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use Mark Wrang's answer failed for me.  While Piemol's comment from Jan 30 '19 solved a basic problem with Mark Wrang's answer, it also didn't work for me.

JSON strings do not always represent rectangular data sets.  They may contain ragged data.  For example, the Power BI activities log outputs JSON that contains different members depending on variables like what activities occurred in the requested data or what features were available at the time.

Using Piemol's comment, I processed this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "a":  "Value 1",
        "b":  20,
        "g":  "Arizona"
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 2",
        "b":  40,
        "c":  "2022-01-01T11:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 3",
        "d":  "omicron",
        "c":  "2022-01-01T12:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "a":  "Value 4",
        "b":  60,
        "d":  "delta",
        "e":  14,
        "c":  "2022-01-01T13:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

The script produced this CSV:

```
"a","b","g"
"Value 1","20","Arizona"
"Value 2","40",
"Value 3",,
"Value 4","60",
```

Notice that columns c, d, and e are missing.  It appears that Export-CSV uses the first object passed to determine the schema for the CSV to output.

To handle this, use the [UnifyProperties function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed/44429084#44429084):

```
function UnifyProperties {
  $Names = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  $InputCollected = @($Input)
  $InputCollected.ForEach({ 
    foreach ($Name in $_.psobject.Properties.Name) { $Null = $Names.Add($Name) }
  })
  $inputCollected | Select-Object @($Names)
}

$pathToInputFolder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path + "\" + "PowerBIActivities\combined\"
$pathToInputFile = $pathToInputFolder + "Activities.json"
$pathToOutputFile = $pathToInputFolder + "Activities.csv"

$content = Get-Content -Path $pathToInputFile -Raw
$psObj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content

$psObj | UnifyProperties | Export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You are over complicating it. A simple function like the one shown on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/15339544) can solve this problem and is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks.  If you can make that work for the example in my answer, I'd love to see it.  I can't make it work.  Plus, that function is 8 lines.  it would replace maybe 5 lines of my code?  Not sure what I'm missing here since I'm new to PowerShell.

Comment: Using the function from that answer an assuming you have the Json converted as an object it would be as simple as `$json | UnifyProperties | Export-Csv ...`. And yes, that code is more efficient because, first, it's using just 1 loop where yours is using 2 and second, you're adding properties to the objects with `Add-Member` which is highly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks.  That is easy.  The usage instructions weren't clear to me.  I was trying to use it to combine pairs of objects from my array rather than just processing the entire array (`$json`).  I'll update my answer.