# Powershell export nested Json to CSV as row

Tags: json, powershell, csv, nested, export

The Json contains the following structure, I would like to convert the values to rows and then insert the rows into a CSV file using Powershell:

the expected My CSV output would be like the one hereunder. I would like the GUID to be repeated for each URL and other Image attributes. Many thanks for looking into the request and for your help.

CSV Output sample

[CSV outout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3uVc.png)

```
enter code here
"_embedded": {
    "assets": [{
        "guid": "49EDBE70-2B28-3AD7-B993-7F68972BA1",
        "images": [{
            "URL": "https://www.rc.com/eqent_images/2020183/thumb/12014855_1.jpg",
            "imageSize": "thumb",
            "imageType": "OTHER",
            "angleNo": 1,
            "photoGuid": "aeb75f64-9005-472-a85a-f857a7b8e27"
        }, {
            "URL": "https://www.rc.com/eqt_images/2020183/largest/12014855_1.jpg",
            "imageSize": "largest",
            "imageType": "OTHER",
            "angleNo": 1,
            "photoGuid": "aeb75f64-9005-47f2-a85a-f857a7b8e27"
        }],
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://www.rc.com/asset-images/guid/49EDBE70-2B9-3AD7-B993-7F670472BA10?imageSize=thumbnail&imageSize=largest&angleNo=1{&imageType}",
                "templated": true
            }
        }
    }, {
        "guid": "D7C5B69C-083C-7598-2762-B57D64B4D82",
        "images": [{
            "URL": "https://www.rc.com/equipment_images/2090183/thumb/12050336_1.jpg",
            "imageSize": "thumb",
            "imageType": "OTHER",
            "angleNo": 1,
            "photoGuid": "11e196a8-02d3-42ae-9620-1a992516a50"
        }, {
            "URL": "https://www.rc.com/eqnt_images/2020183/largest/12050336_1.jpg",
            "imageSize": "largest",
            "imageType": "OTHER",
            "angleNo": 1,
            "photoGuid": "11e196a8-02d3-42ae-9620-1a7f251a950"
        }],
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://www.rc.com/asset-images/guid/D7C8969C-083C-7598-2762-B57D6994D82E?imageSize=thumbnail&imageSize=largest&angleNo=1{&imageType}",
                "templated": true
            }
        }
    }]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://www.rc.com/assetdata-imagescall/search/byGUIDSString?imageSize=thumbnail&imageSize=largest&angleNo=1&page=0&size=1500"
    }
},
"page": {
    "size": 1500,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
}
```

}

Comment: Please read and follow [mcve] rules (pictures are unwelcome).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten a nested JSON with array and filter to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340113/flatten-a-nested-json-with-array-and-filter-to-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a correctly formatted JSON called `j.json`, you could potentially do the following:

```
# Read JSON as a PowerShell Object
$obj = Get-Content j.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Loop through each asset as it contains the GUIDs and Images
$output = $obj._embedded.assets | Foreach-Object {
    # Keep track of Guid as we loop through images
    $guid = $_.Guid
    # Loop through the images to find each URL
    # Use calculated property to create GUID property
    $_.Images | Select-Object @{n='GUID';e={$guid}},URL
}

# Convert to CSV on console only. Not needed if outputting to file
$output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType

# Output to CSV file
$output | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoType
```

See [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) for information on calculated properties.

Comment: Perfect answer, this works like a charm! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the fast response. Just a note : I received the error "ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (1): {" may be the Json is not in correct format. I modified it '$obj =  Get-Content $sourceFilePath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json' everything else is same.