# How to convert nested JSON to CSV powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm running into an issue where my Powershell code isn't working.

```
 $pathToJsonFile='C:\Users\<redacted>\'
 $InputFile= Read-Host -prompt 'Specify a target file'
 $OutputFile= Read-Host -prompt 'Specify a destination file'
 ((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile$InputFile) | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 64).results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content $pathToJsonFile$OutputFile
```

The error I keep getting is:

> 4 |  … om-Json -Depth 64).results | ConvertTo-Csv
> -NoTypeInformation | Set-C …
> |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

I'm not sure what the issue is since I'm piping one result into another. Referencing this post: [Convert JSON to CSV using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594860/convert-json-to-csv-using-powershell)

I'm also not sure what Depth is used for because I have two-layers of nested JSON I'm trying to get to do the conversion correctly.

Comment: Sounds like the json document doesn't have a `results` top-level property.

Comment: So, Depth is just how many nested layers do you want to go into the JSON. To your main point, you won't be able to directly convert nested JSON into csv. You will have to do some data manipulation to do this.

Comment: Could you put an example of your JSON?

Comment: {
  "image_name": "",
  "docker_image_id": "",
  "tag": "",
  "platform": "docker",
  "findings": [
    {
      "nvdFinding": {
        "published_date": "",
        "cpe": [],
        "remediation": "",
        "references": [
          "https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28768",
          "https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2022/10/msg00021.html"
        ]
      },
      "packages": [
        {
          "name": "libc-bin",
          "version": "2.28-10+deb10u1",
          "type": "linux"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
}

Comment: It's a bit butchered

Comment: sounds like @MathiasR.Jessen is correct. You don't have a "results" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the original command addresses a `results` property in the deserialized object, which doesn't appear to exist in your schema. If the objective is to project a different property, say the `packages` array in the first `findings` element, to a CSV, you'd want to change your command to something like (note I added the quotes around the paths too):

```
$pathToJsonFile='C:\Users\<redacted>\'
$InputFile= Read-Host -prompt 'Specify a target file'
$OutputFile= Read-Host -prompt 'Specify a destination file'
((Get-Content -Path "$pathToJsonFile$InputFile") | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 64).findings[0].packages | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content "$pathToJsonFile$OutputFile"
```

**More Info**

Adjusting the original command:

```
((Get-Content -Path ".\test.json") | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 64).results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content .\test.csv
```

Where `test.json` contains:

```
{
    results: [
        { name: "Bill", age: 38 },
        { name: "Jeff", age: 39 },
        { name: "Ruby", age: 40 }   
    ]
}
```

Will yield a new file `test.csv` which contains:

```
"name","age"
"Bill","38"
"Jeff","39"
"Ruby","40"
```